# Lipschitz continuity of bilinear function

Tags: real-analysis

For a bilinear function $T$, it can be shown that $\lVert T(x,y)\rVert\leq C \lVert x\rVert \lVert y \rVert$

I saw some books say a bilinear function T is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $C$ given the above inequality holds.

Now I'm confused because a function T is Lipschitz if $\lVert T(\alpha)-T(\beta)\rVert \leq C \lVert \alpha - \beta \rVert$. So for a bilinear function $T:R^2 \rightarrow R$ to be Lipschitz, it means $\lVert T(x_1,y_1)- T(x_2,y_2)\rVert \leq C \lVert \langle x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2\rangle \rVert$. I can't figure out how this inequality is equivalent to the above one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator norm on product space](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46355/operator-norm-on-product-space)

Answer (score 1):

At least from the usual Lipschitz condition we can derive that $\|T(x,y)\|\leq C\sqrt{\|x\|\|y\|}$. Indeed, since $T(x,y) = T(x,y) - T(x,0) = T(x,y) - T(0,y)$, assuming Lip. of $T$ we obtain two independent abounds: $\|T\|\leq C_1\|x\|$ and $\|T\|\leq C_2\|y\|$. May be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly incorrect.
For example: T(x,y) = xy is bilinear, and $|T(x,y)| \leq |x||y|$
However, it isn't Lipschiz 1, since for example |T(1,2)-T(2,2)|=2, but |(1,2)-(2,2)|=1

Comment: Indeed, a more-than-one-linear function is never Lipschitz.

Comment: @scineram Correct me if I am wrong, but the map $(x,y) \mapsto x+y$ is bilinear and Lipschitz.

Comment: I think they mean the root of T is Lipschitz